# Position info box next to autosized gallery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two demos hosted on an external site:

The page without text shows the expected behavior with proper autosizing.
My first question is: Why does the info div not shrink to the width of the wrapper at the second and third picture?

And the main question: How could I place the info box at the right side of the images, so that the wrapper sizes properly to the combined with of image and text and stays at the center of the viewport?

I tried floating but that didn`t work with unsized elements.

Thanks in advance.

---

I have the following setup:

```js
// jQuery (gets cleaned up later):

$(document).ready(init);

function init() {
  $(".active").on("load", function(evt) {
    setActive($(this).parent(), $(this));
  });

  $(".images").on("click", "img", function() {
    showNextImage($(this).parent());
  });
}

function showNextImage(parent) {
  if(parent.find(".active").next("img").length != 0)
    setActive(parent, parent.find(".active").next("img"));
  else
    setActive(parent, parent.find("img:first"));
}

function setActive(parent, element) {
  parent.find(".active").removeClass("active").css("z-index", 0);
  element.addClass("active");
  element.css("z-index", 10);

  autoSizeParent(parent, element);
}

function autoSizeParent(parent, element) {
  parent.width(element.width());
  parent.height(element.height());
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 1em;
  background: white;
}

.images {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 540px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="images">
    <img class="active" src="http://i.imgur.com/94WEXSB.gif" />            
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/C0JSZMJ.gif" />           
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/bfDOcv1.gif" />           
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam incidunt perferendis, porro natus obcaecati ut! Voluptate perferendis, dicta, perspiciatis blanditiis eligendi ab optio, culpa totam laboriosam veniam ipsam repellendus, ullam.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, I moved stuff around to make it easier for others to read your question. :-p You can host those images on imgur so you do not have to link to your site. The embedded snippet runs. It is preferred to view in full-screen.

Comment: That's better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok now I love display: flex

```
.wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;

    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    padding: 1em;
    background: white;
}

.images {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.info {
    width: 462px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 540px;
}
```

To place info under the images flex-direction: column on wrapper. Info width set by js.